# I just can't figure out Project Plugin in VIM

Tags: vim, plugins, text-editor, project

I am trying to use VIM for some programming. I am a total beginner in VIM. Could you guys please help me figure out [Project Plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69)

I can't understand the documentation. If you have used this plugin, could you tell me the basic steps to get started?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to configure the project plugin, you must edit the .vimprojects file. An example is given in the help

```
:help project-example
```

As you will see, you have to write something like this

```
Name_of_project = path/to/your/project CD=. flags=flags_you_want{
  file1
  file2
  ...

  Name_of_Subcategory = path/to/your/subcategory filter=files_you_want{
   subcategory_file1
   subcategory_file2
   ...
  }
}
```

Now you can call your project:

```
:Project
```

This will open a vertical window with the file you've just configured. Click on any file you added to open it.

For the flags and the filter, everything is explained in the help file. There are others subtleties you'll have to discover by yourself.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, where is the .vimproject file? Where should i create this file?

Comment: You must create it in your home directory.

Comment: on Windows, you might have to call it '_vimprojects' with a starting _, not dot.

Answer (score 12):

You can also have the plugin generate the file for you: invoke `:Project` in normal mode, and then hit `\C` which will prompt you for the name of the project, the directory of the project (i.e., ~/Projects/Foobar if ~/Projects/Foobar contains all your code, et cetera), the `cd` parameter (always the same as the directory, for me) and a standard file filter (`*.cpp` or what have you).

You can then write this projects file out with `:w filename` and load it later on.

Comment: NOTE: for those of you who are stuck in windows. I set up xWin Server so I can load gvim via xterm. When using the \C in gvim,  it will crash after entering the name of the project. I have not traced why this happens however everything works fine under by running standard vim.